# Cannot display the variable in the blade template from the controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I cannot figure out how to display the route name in the blade template of laravel. Please find below the sample code. Thank you.

**from the controller (StaffsController.php)**

```
public function index()
{
    $thisRoute = Route::current()->uri();
    return view('staff.list')>with(compact('thisRoute'));
}
```

**Blade:**

```
{{ $thisRoute }}
```

**This is the var_dump**

```
/home/vagrant/Code/spark/app/Http/Controllers/StaffsController.php:20:string 'staffs' (length=6)
```

**Error:**

```
(1/1) UnexpectedValueException
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
```

**When i change the code in the controller to:**

```
public function index()
{
    $thisRoute = Route::current()->uri();
    return dd($thisRoute);

}
```

I get "staffs" as output which is correct which is a string from the dump, right?

Comment: What do you expect to be printed?

Comment: Why in `dd` you use `Route::current()->uri()` but in first sample just `Route::current();`?

Comment: Also https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#accessing-the-current-route

Comment: @u_mulder, sorry this is a typo. I corrected the code.

Comment: @Laerte I want to output staffs as string in the blade

Answer (score 0):

change your return statement to be like this :

```
return view('staff.list', compact('thisRoute'));
```

if you are using laravel 5.3 or above you can get route name like this:

```
Route::currentRouteName();
```

with this, you really don't have to passe it from your controller to the view just use it directly from your blade view :

```
{{ Route::currentRouteName() }}
```

Comment: sorry mate, changed the code to `$thisRoute = Route::currentRouteName();
        return view('staff.list')>with(compact('thisRoute'));` but stil got the same error

Comment: please change your return statement like this : return view('staff.list', compact('thisRoute'));

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I solved the issue. I missed `-` in the line 
`return view('staff.list')>with(compact('thisRoute'));`

Changed it to

```
return view('staff.list')->with(compact('thisRoute'));
```

I made a mistake.

Thank you

Comment: you could also use the short syntax : `return view('staff.list', compact('thisRoute')); `